# How to calculate CIs for a contingency table in R

Tags: r, confidence-interval, contingency

I have a k x l table of sample proportions computed from a k x l contingency table.
And I would like to compute CIs of sample proportions of the table using R.

There are several ways to do this for a 1 x k table filled with proportions.
But what about a k x l table?
Can I do this to the k x l proportion table in a row-wise or a column-wise way, depending on the way of calculation?

For example, I have a teble like following;

```
       A     B     C     D
X  0.225 0.637 0.108 0.029
Y  0.455 0.171 0.252 0.122

from a contingency table,

    A  B  C  D
X  23 65 11  3
Y  56 21 31 15
```

Is it theoretically okay to get the CIs as follows?

```
mat <- matrix(c(23, 65, 11, 3, 56, 21, 31, 15),
              ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)

MultinomCI(mat[1, ],
           conf.level = 0.95,
           method = "sisonglaz")

MultinomCI(mat[2, ],
           conf.level = 0.95,
           method = "sisonglaz")
```

I wonder there might be a better way, or a function.

Any comments and answers would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it theoretically OK to analyze each row of your matrix separately? I'd say yes, but be careful about the interpretation you provide. OK to discuss X and Y separately, but not their interaction. Also, the small sample size (n < 5) in the first row may be problematic. There is an SAS function that handles this type of case. See https://www.jstatsoft.org/htaccess.php?volume=05&type=i&issue=06&paper=true

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I checked the paper and found that the R function  `MultinomCI` can handle the issue as well. Now I don't quite understand why we cannot discuss interaction in this kind of situation. Does it mean X-Y interaction is a kind of multiple comparison?

Comment: I could be wrong, but my understating of the multinomCI method is that its confidence intervals help us sort out if the elements of X are different from each other, and whether the elements of Y are different from each other. But my suspicion is that those CIs are not really meant for inferring more complex relationships (like possible interactions) between elements of X to elements of Y.